# How to forward message from channel to the groups on telegram bot?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

im trying to implement my bot a function. Function that if the channel write any message it will be forwarded to the groups where the bot already is.

Trying to use scope method that worked like a charm on welcome message when new user joined the group.

```
//index.js

const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot'),

tg = new Telegram.Telegram('MYAPI', {
workers: 1
});

const ForwardController = require('./controllers/forward')

tg.router.when(new Telegram.TextCommand('/info', 'infoCommand'), new InfoController())
.otherwise(new ForwardController());

//forward.js

const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');

class ForwardController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController {
handle(scope) {
    if ('channel' == scope.message.chat._type) {
        scope.api.forwardMessage(scope.message._chat._id, _forwardFromChat._text);
      }
   }
}

module.exports = ForwardController;
```

I tried many combinations but the message is never forwarded... The bot is already administrator on the channel and is also putted in the groups. (Have also private message opened with bot so i think it should forward also there)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [API reference for the library](https://github.com/Naltox/telegram-node-bot/blob/f295c6e32040325ae83d11031812c1490577da80/lib/mvc/Scope.js), the documentation page appears to be down so Github is your friend.

The `forwardMessage` call you are making has incorrect arguments and is accessing the private class variables. It is also returning a promise so you should await the promise or chain a `.then` to it. You can use the class methods on the `Scope` instance itself.

It should be more like:

```
// using async/await - note the containing function must be async for this approach
const result = await forwardMessage(<id of chat here>, scope.message().id());

// or to chain a .then
forwardMessage(<id of chat here>, scope.message().id())
  .then(result => /* do something with result */)
  .catch(err => /* handle the error */);
```

This will use the `Scopes` instance method and handle sending the id of the current chat for you, all you need is the id of the chat you want to send the message to and then replace the `<id of chat here>` with that id.

Comment: Unfortunately cannot use await it throwed error:
`scope.forwardMessage(idofgroup, scope._message._messageId);` I think something is missing..

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Naltox/telegram-node-bot/issues/206)
After long time spent i think there is something messed up inside library and need's to be fixed so i also opened issue on github..
`[error]   
No processor found for update: Update {` This error is the problem i think..